# User data outside aspnet database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to store user data outside the aspnet db (on top of whatever aspnet db requires).

I don't want to extend aspnet db with new properties, i'm perfectly happy with the default implementation and i'm using the user GUID as a pivot point between my user and the aspnet db user.

I activated social connections (Facebook Google & twitter) and i'm wondering when it would be a good time to "link" the user GUID on aspnet db with the user i'd create in my own db. In the case of registering without social buttons it's easy, i can do it in the register action, but where should i do this for social buttons?

Or better yet is there some form of event i could subsribe for when a user is created regardless of how it is created? My goal is to say "whenever a new user is created, create a default initialized user in my db with same guid". Am i doing this the wrong way by doing it in the register action?

Comment: If you want to perform some action when a user registers, the register action sounds like a pretty good place to me.

Comment: but the register action isn't called if you log in (from a social network) without registering the classical way, only if you actually register on the website, so it doesn't allow me to catch all users that have an account on my website, only those who have a standard non social account